# Perform lookup between dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i have multiple dictionary in variable called stats

```
print (stats)
```

```
{'CAT1': [{'Fruit': 'Apple', 'Sound': 'Meow', 'Sleep': 'Normal', 'Color': 'blue', 'Eye': 'blue', 'Tail': 'Short'}]}
{'CAT2': [{'Fruit': 'Orange', 'Sound': 'Meow', 'Sleep': 'Less', 'Color': 'orange', 'Eye': 'black', 'Tail': 'long'}]}
{'CAT3': [{'Fruit': 'Mango', 'Sound': 'Meow', 'Sleep': 'Abnormal', 'Color': 'blue', 'Eye': 'black', 'Tail': 'Short'}]}
{'CAT4': [{'Fruit': 'Peach', 'Sound': 'Meow', 'Sleep': 'Normal', 'Color': 'yellow', 'Eye': 'black', 'Tail': 'short'}]}
```

and i have another dictionary-Owner

```
print(Owner)
```

```
{'CAT1': ['this cat belongs to YZMIKE'], 'CAT2': ['this cat belongs to AAJOHN'], 'CAT3': ['this cat belongs to FPROB'], 'CAT4': ['this cat belongs to LDKATE']}
```

i want to do lookup based on KEY in both dictionary to have below output

```
{
'this cat belongs to YZMIKE':[{'Fruit': 'Apple', 'Sound': 'Meow', 'Sleep': 'Normal', 'Color': 'blue', 'Eye': 'blue', 'Tail': 'Short'}]
'this cat belongs to AAJOHN':[{'Fruit': 'Orange', 'Sound': 'Meow', 'Sleep': 'Less', 'Color': 'orange', 'Eye': 'black', 'Tail': 'long'}]
'this cat belongs to FPROB':[{'Fruit': 'Mango', 'Sound': 'Meow', 'Sleep': 'Abnormal', 'Color': 'blue', 'Eye': 'black', 'Tail': 'Short'}]
'this cat belongs to LDKATE':[{'Fruit': 'Peach', 'Sound': 'Meow', 'Sleep': 'Normal', 'Color': 'yellow', 'Eye': 'black', 'Tail': 'short'}]
}
```

Appreciate your help...i am new to python and not sure how i can perform this lookup..

Comment: Your data isn't valid dictionary/list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how:

```
stats = {'CAT1': [{'Fruit': 'Apple', 'Sound': 'Meow', 'Sleep': 'Normal', 'Color': 'blue', 'Eye': 'blue', 'Tail': 'Short'}],
         'CAT2': [{'Fruit': 'Orange', 'Sound': 'Meow', 'Sleep': 'Less', 'Color': 'orange', 'Eye': 'black', 'Tail': 'long'}],
         'CAT3': [{'Fruit': 'Mango', 'Sound': 'Meow', 'Sleep': 'Abnormal', 'Color': 'blue', 'Eye': 'black', 'Tail': 'Short'}],
         'CAT4': [{'Fruit': 'Peach', 'Sound': 'Meow', 'Sleep': 'Normal', 'Color': 'yellow', 'Eye': 'black', 'Tail': 'short'}]}


Owner = {'CAT1': ['this cat belongs to YZMIKE'],
         'CAT2': ['this cat belongs to AAJOHN'],
         'CAT3': ['this cat belongs to FPROB'],
         'CAT4': ['this cat belongs to LDKATE']}

d = {Owner[v1][0]:stats[v2] for v1,v2 in zip(Owner.keys(),stats.keys()) if v1==v2}

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{ 'this cat belongs to YZMIKE':[{'Fruit': 'Apple', 'Sound': 'Meow', 'Sleep': 'Normal', 'Color': 'blue', 'Eye': 'blue', 'Tail': 'Short'}],
  'this cat belongs to AAJOHN':[{'Fruit': 'Orange', 'Sound': 'Meow', 'Sleep': 'Less', 'Color': 'orange', 'Eye': 'black', 'Tail': 'long'}],
  'this cat belongs to FPROB':[{'Fruit': 'Mango', 'Sound': 'Meow', 'Sleep': 'Abnormal', 'Color': 'blue', 'Eye': 'black', 'Tail': 'Short'}],
  'this cat belongs to LDKATE':[{'Fruit': 'Peach', 'Sound': 'Meow', 'Sleep': 'Normal', 'Color': 'yellow', 'Eye': 'black', 'Tail': 'short'}] }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a problem in your data formats in your question.  It looks like you have two dictionaries with the same keys, So if you want to create a dictionary that replaces the keys in dict 1 with the values found within the list in dict 2:

```
new_dict = dict((Owner[x][0],stats[x]) for x in stats)
```

or to be extra safe:

```
new_dict = dict((Owner[x][0],stats[x]) for x in stats if x in Owner)
```

Comment: Thanks RufusVS, how to avoid key error if match is not found in stats

Comment: I think you mean if match not found in Owner.  It is already in stats.   I'll add that to answer.